# The usage of *undoubtedly*,*doubtless*, *doubtlessly* and *no doubt*

Tags: adverbs, synonyms

I found out that *doubtless* can be used as an adverb as well as *undoubtedly*.And I don't see the difference. Could someone kindly explain if there's any? Then I found *doubtlessly*, which is not in every dictionary. Why? Isn't it quite correct to use that? All of them seem to mean "certainly" or "without doubt". Is there any difference in usage?Thank you.

Comment: Some people will ***doubtless*** say that in this sentence I'm primarily implying that ***I** have no doubts about my claim.* And if I say it's ***undoubtedly*** true, that might be taken to imply that ***no-one** doubts it*. All I know for sure is that learners can safely ignore any such distinction - they just need to remember not to use ***doubtlessly*** in *any* context (it's never necessary, and I doubt there are any contexts where it would be "preferred" either).

Comment: @FumbleFingers so, there's some difference .Can I use both of them to modify a verb (people will undoubtedly say) and adjectives(it is doubtless true)?? Would that sound natural?

Comment: I said *some* people would claim that difference (not *me*). Not that I'd necessarily know (or indeed *care*) whether others might agree, but personally I think if there *is* a shade of difference, it's that ***undoubtedly*** might be a little more "emphatic" (partly because it's a bit longer and "posher-sounding", but ***indubitably*** wins hands-down on "gravitas" in that respect).

Comment: Actually, although there's not really any difference in *meaning*, there is a potential (but really tiny) difference in "acceptable syntax". Overall, they've been used about equally for centuries, but for reasons that aren't clear to me, we'd virtually never refer to ***a doubtless good X***, whereas we *do* quite naturally refer to ***an undoubtedly good** [idea, say, which unfortunately won't work for some reason]*. But although ***doubtless*** doesn't work *quite* so well as an adjective before a noun, it's not ungrammatical.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, what? There's one more!

Comment: There's always more one can say about *any* choice of words (no two different ways of saying something are ever completely equal in all respects). It's *feasible* grammarians and pedants have opined about possible distinctions before me, but for all I know they might have different opinions anyway. From a learners perspective, it's doubtless sufficient to say you can treat them as equivalent - many people may prefer one or the other, or use them differently, but they won't all make the *same* choices and distinctions.

Comment: Thank you, there's no such info anywhere. They aren't interchangeable then.

Comment: For the umpteenth time, so far as anyone learning English needs to care, THEY **ARE** INTERCHANGEABLE! I'm just making some very subtle points that might be interesting to a few people. But it seems my doubtless good intentions might just be leading you to think that this very sentence is invalid. Whereas undoubtedly lots of native speakers wouldn't have a clue whether or why it wasn't quite an optimal choice of adverb there.

Comment: (That's to say, the reason you find "no such info anywhere" is because to all intents and purposes it's not really "known" information anyway. Just some *usage tendencies* that can in principle be analysed.)